# How to pass variables from __init__ to Meta class in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create a dynamic form from columns in a database.
The columns are different for every table but I must be able to add a table and then Django needs to be able to create a form to insert new values without having to modify the code.

views.py

```
def add_entry(request, partname):
    partname = partname.replace('_', ' ').title().replace(' ', '')

    form = AddPartForm(request.POST, model=partname)

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Passing the model from views.py to forms.py works like

```
class AddPartForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model = kwargs.pop('model')
        super(AddPartForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
ValueError: ModelForm has no model class specified.
```

I can't seem to get that model variable to the Meta class.

Is there a way to do this or should I approach it in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need and I solved it by constructing the form class dynamically:

```
def get_modelform(name, model, baseclass):
    meta = type('Meta', (), { "model":model})
    return type(name, (baseclass,), {"Meta": meta})
```

Then you have to change your view this way:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
    def add_entry(request, partname):
        partname = partname.replace('_', ' ').title().replace(' ', '')
        model = AppConfig.get_model('yourapp', partname)
        form = get_modelform('AddPartForm', model, forms.ModelForm)(request.POST)
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: I am puzzling with your code, it sounds like it should work but I get the same error. Could you be a little bit more specific or am I missing something?